# How to make a script which automatically copies game save files to a flash drive after the game is closed

Tags: debian, ubuntu, synchronization, minecraft

Disclaimer: I have used Linux for two years. Despite exploring so much in these wonderful times, I am still a horrible N008 at this. So please pardon me if the solution seems obvious. Besides, I have only used debian based distros.

So, I have been working on a project: Simplified Portable Minecraft for Linux. Well, it's not technically finished yet. So I have formatted a 32GB USB Flash Drive to ext4 (gparted ftw!!!) and made an autorun script which:

1. Copies updated game data on flash drive to .minecraft folder in the User's folder (eradicating the older one.)
2. Launches Minecraft from a .jar file.

Now, I want it to copy updated game data back to the pendrive once it is closed. Here's a sample of the code in autorun.sh . Can you help me?

```
#!/bin/bash -l
#$ -S /bin/bash
#$ -N $1

rm -rf ~/.minecraft
cp -rn  /media/$1/MC/minecraft  ~/
mv /home/$1/minecraft /home/$1/.minecraft
java -jar Minecraft.jar
```

$1 stands for the user. Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't you just move the folder back?

```
#!/bin/bash -l
#$ -S /bin/bash
#$ -N $1

rm -rf ~/.minecraft
cp -rn  /media/$1/MC/minecraft  ~/.minecraft
java -jar Minecraft.jar
rm -rf /media/$1/MC/minecraft
cp -rn ~/.minecraft /media/$1/MC/minecraft
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Ahem...you kind of missed my point. I need a way to make the computer move the folder back once the minecraft process is terminated. Sorry, but my question is still unanswered as I need it to do it automagically. No user intervention whatsoever.

Comment: That's what the script does! All the user needs to do is start the script. The script will `move the folder back onve the minecraft process is terminated`. No user intervention is required. What else is required?